# Direct access to Swift's UTF-16 code units

Tags: swift

I need direct access to the underlying UTF-16 code units for a Swift string. While it is possible to get a pointer to the UTF-8 C characters with:

```
string.utf8CString.withUnsafeBufferPointer { utf8chars in
    ...
}
```

there doesn't seem to be any equivalent for UTF-16 code units, which is odd since Swift strings are internally stored as UTF-16.

The closest I can get is to wrap the UTF16 view in an array:

```
ContiguousArray(string.utf16).withUnsafeBufferPointer { utf16units in
    ...
}
```

but this is drastically slower than direct access to the code units.

Is there some hidden method of getting at the underlying UTF-16 code units that I am missing?

Comment: Strings are natively stored internally as unicode scalar values (21 bits per unit), and what you have access to are characters which could have various lengths in bytes due to being more than 1 unicode scalar value.  I think you are confusing it with NSString

Comment: @Knight0fDragon: As far as I remember it from looking at the source code, the characters are *internally* stored as bytes (for pure ASCII strings) or UTF-16 code units, but I may be wrong of course.

Comment: @MartinR I am looking at apple docs https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html,

Comment: `Behind the scenes, Swift’s native String type is built from Unicode scalar values. A Unicode scalar is a unique 21-bit number for a character or modifier, such as U+0061 for LATIN SMALL LETTER A ("a"), or U+1F425 for FRONT-FACING BABY CHICK ("").`

Comment: @Knight0fDragon: I am looking at https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/StringCore.swift: "The core implementation of a highly-optimizable String that can store both ASCII and UTF-16, and can wrap native Swift _StringBuffer or NSString instances".

Comment: @MartinR looks like `utf8CString` goes off of the `utf8view`,  I do not see anywhere you could access the StringBuffer in the String

Comment: Do you have some self-contained example code which demonstrates the performance problem?

Comment: I did a simple test and observed that your UTF-16 code is indeed slower (by a factor 2) for *pure ASCII* strings. That makes sense because these are internally stored as ASCII bytes, and the conversion to UTF-8 is trivial. But for strings containing non-ASCII characters I could not observe a significant difference.